# Is SICP still relevant?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, books

Today, I came across [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262510871) entitled:*The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*

I read the Table Of Contents and it really interests, me. It seems to be exactly what I've been looking for! From what I've read online, the book seems to have been pretty influential.

However, everyone who read it, read it like 20 years ago from what it seems.

Does the book still provide valuable knowledge?
Has it been superseded by another influential book I should be aware of?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7431861/3001761

Comment: off-site resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: The best programming books are *still* relevant [nearly 50 years later](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming). If its an old programming book and still in print, it is probably a good one.

Comment: Well, it's no longer in print, sadly. But it is available for free on the MIT website.

Comment: @JörgWMittag you can buy it, hard copy on Amazon. (perhaps new copies aren't being made though)

Comment: @gnat: This isn't a recommendation question.  Recommendation questions ask "which book is best?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey is SICP still a _recommended_ reading?

Comment: Absolutely.  As Jörg states below, it's still as relevant as ever.

Comment: I see. Thanks for sharing [your _opinion_](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> However, everyone who read it, read it like 20 years ago from what it seems.

Actually, it was the basis of MIT's 6.001 introduction to programming until fairly recently, and still is used for similar courses in other universities even today.

> Has it been superseded by another influential book I should be aware of?

Not really.

There are other books that take different approaches to teaching, such as [*How to Design Programs*](http://HtDP.Org/), which was specifically [created to address certain perceived shortcomings in SICP](http://WWW.CCS.NEU.Edu/scheme/pubs/jfp2004-fffk.pdf), or [*Concrete Abstractions*](https://Gustavus.Edu/+max/concrete-abstractions.html), but SICP is still a timeless classic.

Abstraction, Reuse, Analytic Thinking, Program Design, those aren't things that just go out of fashion.

Personally, I'd recommend starting with HtDP, and then move on to SICP, but that's just my opinion.